# Installing TestStack.White through Package Manager Console in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, package, ui-automation, nuget-package

I'm trying to install TestStack.White with NuGet through the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio but when I enter the "Install-Package TestStack.White" command in the Package Manager Console I get this error:

```
Installing 'Castle.Core 3.3.3'.
Successfully installed 'Castle.Core 3.3.3'.
Installing 'TestStack.White 0.13.3'.
Successfully installed 'TestStack.White 0.13.3'.
The names of some imported commands from the module 'TestStack.White' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
Adding 'Castle.Core 3.3.3' to PSTableManager.
Uninstalling 'Castle.Core 3.3.3'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Castle.Core 3.3.3'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Castle.Core 3.3.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Native,Version=v0.0', but the package does 
not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you cannot install this package is because it is not compatible with your project. Package TestStack.White is .NET based (managed), so it cannot be added to a native C++ project:

```
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Native,Version=v0.0', but the package does 
not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.
```

There is a managed version of C++, it is called C++/CLI. You can try using that along with TestStack.White package. However, this depends on requirements of your project. If you must create a native app, then you cannot use C++/CLI.